# Using Sitecore PowerShell Extensions to Copy Layout Details from One Device to Another

Tags: powershell-extensions, sitecore-api

My website is using the `App Center Placeholder` device on all of the pages. I would like to use [Sitecore PowerShell Extensions (SPE)](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_PowerShell_console.aspx) to deprecate the `App Center Placeholder` device and move all the associated presentation details for all the pages within `sitecore/content/MyWebSite` to the `Mobile` device instead.

Figure 1 shows the devices. Figure 2 shows an example of where I am currently at. And, Figure 3 is an example of where I want to be.

All the pages have different child controls and the child control properties would also need to be copied to the `Mobile` device from the `App Center Placeholder` device. (See Figure 4)

We are using Sitecore 8.1 Update 3 and SPE 4.6.

**Figure 1**

[image]

**Figure 2**

[image]

**Figure 3**

[image]

**Figure 4**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could loop through the content items you need to update, and then use a string replace to change the `App Center Placeholder` device Id with the `Mobile` device Id.

Here is an example of how you might script it. Caveat - this is untested code, so test it before running it on your entire content tree! Also, with this code, it doesn't check if the item already has content

```
$mobileDeviceId = Get-LayoutDevice -Name "Mobile" | % { $_.Id.Guid.ToString("B") } | Select-Object -First 1
$appCenterDeviceId = Get-LayoutDevice -Name "App Center Placeholder" | % { $_.Id.Guid.ToString("B") } | Select-Object -First 1

$items = Get-ChildItem -Path master:\content\mysite -Recurse 
foreach($item in $items) {
    # Replace the appcenter device id with the mobile device id
    $renderingsText = $item.__Renderings
    $newRenderingsText = $renderingsText.Replace($appCenterDeviceId, $mobileDevice)

    # do the same for the Final Layout
    $finalLayoutText = $item.__Final
    $newFinalLayoutText = $finalLayoutText.Replace($appCenterDeviceId, $mobileDevice)

    $item.Editing.BeginEdit()
    $item["__Renderings"] = $newRenderingsText
    $item["__Final Renderings"] = $newFinalLayoutText
    $item.Editing.EndEdit()
}
```

Comment: `$item.Editing.EndEdit()` is returning false and the `$item` does not seem to be updating.